# Giant memory performance issue on unity game

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, memory

I have a script that spawns 20,000 trees around the scene(non-terrain). However when i play the game, my memory skyrockets because of the thousands of object that spawn in. Is there any way of reducing the amount of memory the game uses? The 3d model of the tree is use is this, but without the leaves. If it helps, here is this the script i use for spawning the trees:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TreeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject treePrefab;
    public float maxTrees = 10000;
    public float spawnedTrees;
    public Transform treeParent;
    private Vector3 treePos;
    private GameObject spawnedTree;
    private TreeRendering spawnedTreeScript;
    public Transform player;
    private bool doneSpawning;
    public GameObject loadingBar;
    public GameObject loadingScreen;
    public LayerMask treeLayer;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start()
    {
        for (spawnedTrees = 0; spawnedTrees < maxTrees; spawnedTrees++)
        {
            float treePosX = Random.Range(-500,500);
            float treePosY = 100;
            float treePosZ = Random.Range(-500, 500);
            RaycastHit treeRay;
            //new Vector3(treePosX, 0, treePosZ)
            if (Physics.Raycast(new Vector3(treePosX, 150, treePosZ), Vector3.down, out treeRay, 200))
            {
                treePosY = treeRay.point.y;
            }
            treePos = new Vector3(treePosX, treePosY, treePosZ);
            spawnedTree = Instantiate(treePrefab, treePos, treePrefab.transform.rotation, treeParent);
            spawnedTreeScript = spawnedTree.GetComponent<TreeRendering>();
            spawnedTreeScript.player = player;
        }
        if (spawnedTrees == maxTrees)
        {
            doneSpawning = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried removing some sticks from the tree, and removing all the leaves but it still uses like 5 gb of ram. I also tried to see if its any different when building the game, but its the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you merge your meshes at runtime.

so generate them, then use this code below to merge them together, this will reduce the memory used as unity will treat it as 1 mesh instead of 20000

This code is untested. but the theory should work in practice.

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class TreeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        // Call a function to merge meshes
        MergeMeshes();
    }

    void MergeMeshes()
    {
        // create your 3000 trees here
        // then get the meshs for each of the trees and then continue with the code below
        // Get all mesh filters in children
        MeshFilter[] meshFilters = GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();

        // Create arrays to store mesh data
        CombineInstance[] combine = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length];

        // Loop through each mesh filter and populate combine array
        for (int i = 0; i < meshFilters.Length; i++)
        {
            combine[i].mesh = meshFilters[i].sharedMesh;
            combine[i].transform = meshFilters[i].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            // Optionally, you can disable the original GameObjects here if needed
            // meshFilters[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        // Create a new empty GameObject to hold the combined mesh
        GameObject combinedMeshObject = new GameObject("CombinedMesh");

        // Add a MeshFilter and MeshRenderer component to the new GameObject
        MeshFilter combinedMeshFilter = combinedMeshObject.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
        MeshRenderer combinedMeshRenderer = combinedMeshObject.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

        // Combine meshes into a single mesh
        combinedMeshFilter.mesh = new Mesh();
        combinedMeshFilter.mesh.CombineMeshes(combine, true, true);

        // Optionally, you can set the material of the combined mesh
        // combinedMeshRenderer.material = yourMaterial;

        // You can also attach any necessary scripts or components to the new GameObject

        // Optionally, destroy the original GameObjects
        // foreach (var meshFilter in meshFilters)
        // {
        //     Destroy(meshFilter.gameObject);
        // }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to merge them (in other words you want all the trees to be independent) perhaps its a good idea to use some sort of chunk system like most games do. Where you could store certain sections of the map, and then load/unload them when they're a certain distance away from the player. I need more information to help though, for example, why do you need so many trees? what are you doing with the trees, is there some sort of functionality you need or are they just there to look nice? Some more info would be helpful.

Comment: So my game plays in a forest. I only make the trees active if they are a certain distance away from the player, but that only has an impact on fps, not memory. I could switch over to a chunk system if thats any better. Im gonna try merging the trees now.

Comment: merging the trees wouldn't work with an unload/load setup as all trees would be combined into a single object and cant be separated, in terms of the memory issue, i recommend loading a small amount of trees in (say 200) only when you generate a new chunk, that way your not loading 20000 at the start but a small amount every so often. Edit: what do you mean by memory? please be more specific, gpu memory, ram?